# Link a person before that person has an account on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I plan to create an firebase tree solution to make possible to some operator link a person to some data before that person has an account.

So, when that person create its account, it will be possible to find that data. I was thinking about create some tree like this:

```
- Before_Signup_Link_User
 - $user_email
   - OperatorONE: true
   - OperatorTWO: true
```

After signup and with its email informed on Firebase, the user would get the operator ID to find data on another path.

**The problem is that Firebase does no let us put email as child.** Do you have some ideia to do that.

Comment: Use Firebase's anonymous login instead then user their `uid` to assign them to the respective operators

Comment: This indeed would take a combination of the answer from umon (encoding the illegal `.` as a `,`) and then using Firebase's anonymous authentication to generate a `uid` for the user before they actually sign in.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use space char instead of dot char.

For Example:

```
- user@mail com
  - OperatorONE: true
  - OperatorTWO: true
```

a basic solution.. :)

Comment: That would work. More idiomatic is to use a `,` instead of a `.`. Not sure why that is more idiomatic by the way, but it's what we use internally at Firebase. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Firebase doesn't allow some special characters (its indicated on their old docs, but I believe its still a valid rule on the new version)

> A child node's key cannot be longer than 768 bytes, nor deeper than 32 levels. It can include any unicode characters except for . $ # [ ] / and ASCII control characters 0-31 and 127.

So if you want to use the email as child, you'll have to provide its proper unicode value